# How can I move a circle on a vertical line on scroll only when this vertical line inn viewport?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I have a vertical line ( not at the top of web page). This line has a circle at top, and I want it(circle) to move downward on scroll when it is in viewport, similarly upwards when I scroll upwards. I cant make this code work. Circle will stop moving after reaching top or bottom of vertical line. Can you help me to find where am I wrong?

This is what I tried:

```
export default function Move() {
  const [scrollPosition, setScrollPosition] = useState(0);
  const lineLength = 900; // Height of the vertical line

  const handleScroll = ([entry]: any) => {
    const currentPosition = Math.min(
      Math.max(entry.intersectionRatio * lineLength, 0),
      lineLength
    );
    setScrollPosition(currentPosition);
  };

  const containerRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const options = {
      root: null,
      rootMargin: "0px",
      threshold: [0, 0.5, 1],
    };

    const observer = new IntersectionObserver(handleScroll, options);

    if (containerRef.current) {
      observer.observe(containerRef.current);
    }

    return () => {
      if (containerRef.current) {
        observer.unobserve(containerRef.current);
      }
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="flex items-center justify-center min-h-screen">
      <div className="relative flex flex-col items-center">
        <div
          className="absolute bg-blue-500 w-5 h-5 rounded-full"
          style={{ top: `${scrollPosition}px` }}
        />
        <div className="h-[900px] w-0.5 bg-gray-400" />
      </div>
      <div ref={containerRef} style={{ height: "0", visibility: "hidden" }} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: This is - I *think* - likely possible with just CSS, and [`position: sticky`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#sticky_positioning), I'm not sure I fully understand your requirements, but [this demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/81kjnhbx/) may achieve your desired result. Note that I've used some JavaScript to randomly assign different box-sizes to the various '.boxes' elements, otherwise CSS does the work.